# LINQ to SQL works locally, but not on server

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

We have some weird error in our .NET WEB application. We have made a LINQ query to take info from database to required model (`DataContext` -> `Model`). It works perfectly well while doing that query in local machines (both my and co-worker's laptops). Thing is, on the server query throws `OutofMemory` exception when making a `.ToList()` request. Question is:

**Why does it work locally, but not on server?**

We have tried to change our connection string to connect to remote database, which is on the server, and it works. But that change didn't make any difference on the server. I have checked the .NET Framework version and it is the same both on our machines and on server.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you post your query here?

Comment: What memory limits has the app pool? If you are on a shared hosting, EF is not a good option.

Comment: Did you try connecting your development machine with the database connected to the server? If so, did you get the same error while on dev machine, or not?

Comment: lexeRoy I don't think that query has something to do with that exception. I'm not allowed to share the code, it's business application.
MikeSW it's a dedicated server, not shared.
@Ali.NET yes, I've tried that. It works.

Comment: When you run the query on the server, is it against the same database or a production database ? Then if that is the case, what is the size of the expected dataset ?

Comment: is it an SQL exception or a .net exception?

Comment: @ChristianDietz it's against the same database, which now is production database (on the server). I'm not sure of the size of dataset, but it's REALLY not that much as .ToList() is using (sometimes more than 1GB RAM).

Comment: @noobob Exception: An exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: ITs not something silly like 64Bit on your developement machine and 32Bit on the server is it?

Comment: @YOhan are you using lazyloading ? Because if you are not, the relations between the data in your database may load way more data than you intended. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.data.objects.objectcontextoptions.lazyloadingenabled%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Bob Vale, of course not :)

@ChristianDietz yes, we are using LazyLoading.

Comment: Does the server have any resource limits set for the application pool?